# ArcPy - Add Layer from Cursor Selection

Tags: arcpy, layers, python-addin, cursor, select-by-location

I am trying to add layers from the fields of a reference layer using select by location and a cursor.  Also, want to prompt the user with a message box asking if they want to add the selected by location.  I am able to print string value from the reference layer when the user responds with "Yes" with the message box, but get an error when passing the string value as a path using "arcpy.mapping.addLayer".

```
def onMouseDownMap(self, x, y, button, shift):     
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd,"*")[0]
    #layer path
    lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\ArcGis\Aerial_Imagery.lyr")
    #Add Layer
    arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, lyr1, "TOP")


    point = arcpy.Point(x, y)
    ptGeometry = arcpy.PointGeometry(point)
    #Select layer by points/mouse down on map
    arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management("Aerial_Imagery.lyr", "INTERSECT", ptGeometry)
    #cursor to display selected layers on field name "Layer_Path"
    cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor("Aerial_Imagery.lyr")
    field = "Layer_Path"
    for row in cursor:
        selpath = (row.getValue(field))
        message = "Would you like to add this Imagery:" + selpath
        Addbutton = pythonaddins.MessageBox(message, "Imagery Finder", 4)
        if Addbutton == "Yes":
            addlyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer(selpath)
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addlyr, "TOP")#this breaks

            print selpath #this works

        else:
            pythonaddins.MessageBox("this is the answer to NO", "no answer", 0)

   #Remove Layer
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Aerial_Imagery.lyr"):
        #print "Remove Layer", lyr
        arcpy.mapping.RemoveLayer(df, lyr)

    #Refresh view and TOC
    arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
    arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

Comment: Please tell us exactly what the error message says.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code looks OK to me so I guess its down to formatting of the string especially with "\" or "/" or "\\" .

This line:

```
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\ArcGis\Aerial_Imagery.lyr")
```

should really be:

```
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\ArcGis\Aerial_Imagery.lyr")
```

or it could be:

```
lyr1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\\ArcGis\\Aerial_Imagery.lyr")
```

So the full path that you are extracting out of image catalog layer should be
formatted correctly. A simple find and replace of "\" with "\\" will work.